# What event should I use to detect an entity is being persisted again but is not being changed?

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I want to trigger an event when updating an entity even if the data didn't change. So, what event should I use?

Remind: I want to **access the entity data**, so I can not use `onFlush`. Besides, since the entity data is not being changed, `preUpate` or `postUpdate` are not triggered.

[Doctrine events docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#events)

Answer (score 0):

You can centralise the persist of the entity in service manager. 
in this manager try to dispatch a general event

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;
...
...
    public function persistAndFlush($entity)
    {
        $this->em->persist($entity);
        $this->em->flush();

        //dispatch an event
        $event = new GenericEvent($entity, array('course_history' => 1));
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(YourClassEvents::UPDATE_ENTITY, $event);
    }
```

Then you can create a listner to listen this generic event

## Edit

**More details**

*assume we have entity Product*

```
namespace Domain\YourBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $productName
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="productName", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $productName;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    //setters and getters
}
```

- Create service manager

> service.xml

```
<service id="yourdomain.product_manager" class="Domain\YourBundle\Service\ProductManager">
    <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager"/>
    <argument type="service" id="event_dispatcher"/>
</service>
```

- Create Our manager

> ProductManager class

```
namespace Domain\YourBundle\Manager;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Domain\YourBundle\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;

class ProductManager
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;
    /**
     * @var EventDispatcherInterface
     */
    protected $dispatcher;
    /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    }

    public function persistAndFlush($product)
    {
        $this->em->persist($product);
        $this->em->flush();

        //The entity is updated then dispatch an event 
        $event = new GenericEvent($product, array('product_name' => 1));
        $this->dispatcher->dispatch('product', $event);
    }
}
```

> Add definition of listener in service.xml

```
<service id="yourdomain.event.update_product" class="Domain\YourBundle\EventListener\UpdateProductListener">

    <argument type="service" id="logger"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="product" method="onUpdateProduct"/>
</service>
```

> class UpdateProductListener

```
namespace Domain\YourBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;
use Domain\YourBundle\Entity\Product;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class UpdateProductListener
{
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    /**
     * Listen the generic event dispatched when the product name is updated
     *
     * @param GenericEvent $event
     *
     * @throws RuntimeException
     * @throws \ErrorException
     */
    public function onUpdateProduct(GenericEvent $event)
    {
        if ($event->getSubject() instanceof Product) {
            $product = $event->getSubject();

            if ($event->hasArgument('product_name') && $event->getArgument('product_name') == 1) {
                /*
                Make your logic (send mail, add log, notification....)
                */
                $this->logger->notice('UpdateProductListener : event update product is occured');

            } else {
                $this->logger->notice('UpdateProductListener : event other than update product is occured.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem here. You want to access entity after update, but the entity is not really updates. So you obviously use DQL query here, and [this disallows you to access pre\postUpdate](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) as you correctly mentioned. The problem is that doctrine does not really knows that the object was changed - the query could be a bit complicated so the object identifier could be hidden to it. Or even not known (in case of MySQL)

Some RDBMs have the `RETURNING` clause, allowing you to see the results of update, but it's not DB abstract, thus could not be accessed from the DQL out of the box.

You can use the native SQL query or do other tricks to fetch updated rows.

If the query is not performance critical I'd rather suggest it to some software (php-side) processing with simple doctrine flush.

If it is - I think it is not possible. If you privde more detail on the use case, the workaround could be discussed.

I.e. you can use [versioning](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#optimistic-locking) iterate all the entities cached at the EM and check the vesrion is changed.